# windows media player doesn't play rtsp stream

Tags: streaming, rtsp, windows-media-player

I am trying to play RTSP stream with Windows Media Player. I succeeded to do this with VLC player, but WMP says that there is a network error. In network options of WMP all possible protocols are checked. The settings of proxy-servers are the following:
HTTP - browser,
RTSP - autodetected.

The stream I am catching is generated on my computer by VLC player. VLC uses RTSP, no coding and the profile Audio-CD. It sends the stream to port number 8554. So in WMP I choose File, Open url and write rtsp://192.00.15.9:8554

I will be very grateful if someone tells me where I do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to stream from VLC to WMP is to use MMS or MMSH, see

http://wiki.videolan.org/Windows_Media_Player#Streaming_from_VLC

Answer (score 0):

http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback_101.swf?src=
 + your rtmp

In wmp12 you can first put the address of the absurd as shown here

http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback_101.swf?src=rtmp://89.34.237.106:1935/stream/2312

Comment: It is better to write more information not just a link